# why both funs are returning the same?

Tags: c++, reference

I have two funcs,

```
struct a
{
public:
    int* b;

    int *& fun1()
    {
        return b;
    }

    int * fun2()
    {
        return b;
    }
};

void main()
{
    a* some = new a;
    some->b = new int(1);

    int* x1 = some->fun1();
    int* x2 = some->fun2();

    return;
}
```

why both are returning the same?
why if `some->b` will be `nullptr` both `func`s will return null without exception?

Comment: Why would they not return the same? You store both in `int*`.

Comment: They are not returning the same. Your test merely overlooks that.

Comment: fun1 returns *& and fun2 returns *,  I expected that in case of some->b == nullptr the fun1 will cause exception

Comment: I have no idea why you would expect that.

Comment: @upiorek why would it cause exception? It just returns a reference to the pointer. Where do you see the exception?

Comment: @StoryTeller please explain it, what should I change to see the difference?

Comment: `some->fun1() = nullptr; int* x2 = some->fun2();` - The other way just won't build. There's a major difference.

Comment: @StoryTeller - ok, I see it. Thanks!

Comment: `main()` returns `int`. Please replace whatever book or tutorial told you it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function returns a reference to the original data member `b` of the object pointed to by `some`. So you can change the original data member `b` using this reference.

But you can not do the same using the second function because it returns a copy of the value of the original data member `b`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

struct a
{
public:
    int *b;

    int * & fun1()
    {
        return b;
    }

    int * fun2()
    {
        return b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    a *some = new a;
    some->b = new int(1);

    some->fun1() = new int( 2 );

    std::cout << *some->b << std::endl;

//  This statement will not compile.    
//  some->fun2() = new int( 3 );

    delete some->b;
    some->b = nullptr;

    delete some;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2
```

If you uncomment the commented statement you will get a compiler error.